# Assigning a String to an ArrayList pulled from file

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I imported a List of `Strings` from a file and put them into an `arrayList`.  I am trying to chop of the end of these arrays, so I'm putting them into a separate `String` format

Here is where i set x

```
x = new ArrayList<BankAccounts>();
try {
    Scanner reader;
    reader = new Scanner( new File("F:\\myCreditUnion.txt") );

    while ( reader.hasNext() )
    {
        String inputLine = reader.nextLine();
        first = inputLine.substring(0, 3);
        second = Double.parseDouble(inputLine.substring(5, inputLine.length()));
        x.add(new BankAccounts(first, second));
    }

    reader.close(); 
}
```

and this is where i try to chop off the end

```
double howmuch;
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
{
     list.equals(x.get(i));
     howmuch = Double.parseDouble(list.substring(5, list.length()));
}
// x is the list
```

I am getting a `nullpointerexception`. Wondering how to fix this, as I am pretty new to programming.

**Document i am importing contains a combinations of # and letters such as, 101s 583.58**

Comment: @alb - Joe had included the code, but it was cutoff by SO's text parser. It was there, it just needed to be better formatted.

Comment: When you get an exception, normally you also get a stack trace, which tells you in which line of your code the exception occurs. Then look which objects are used in this line. If it is in the piece of code you posted, either `x` or `list` are `null`.

Comment: @Joe - Work on your code formatting. Keep everything organized and properly spaced (I like 4 spaces per code block indention myself), and if possible, use Eclipse or some other free editor that helps you keep your code neat and tidy. And, on SO, select your code snippets and then click the `{}` (two curly braces) icon above the edit area. This will properly format your code, so we can read it.

Comment: You add BankAccounts and try to get Strings? That wont work even without a nullpointer exception

Comment: Care to elaborate? Although they are numbers they are being imported as a string

Comment: joe tell us what is list in your code, where you initialize list?

Comment: list is just a string variable

Comment: @joe .. you don't need that string variable at all in there :). Also Java doesn't have "automatic conversion" between types except in very specific cases (primitive types and box/unboxing situations). This means you can't put an object of Type X into a list and expect to get out a String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To assign a value to `list` you have use `list = x.get(i);` instead of `list.equals(x.get(i));`

Update:

- `equals()` does not assign values it only checks if two objects are equal.
- The value returned by x.get(i) will be a BankAccount so you can't assign it to list (which is a String)
- You have to either turn the BankAccount into a String by using toString() or you have to get a String out of it by calling one of the BankAccount methods before assigning it to list, how this works depends on the methods provided by the BankAccount class.

Comment: But there are both strings, so if i do that i get an incompatible types error

Comment: wow thank you, that was very helpful.  Is there a reason though when i do S.O.P(x.get(i)) my answer shows the location in memory and not the actual value

Comment: @joe that is the output of the default toString() implementation, since BankAccount does not define its own toString() you cannot convert BankAccount into a String directly.

Comment: @joe looking at your code again, don't you already split the end of when you create the BankAccount?

Comment: So how do i print what is in an arraylist?

Comment: @joe System.out.println(anArrayList.toString()) prints a list of contents, however for BankAccount it will only print the class and some random numbers. You have to create the string to represent your BankAccount objects yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a NullPointerException in the above code, either `list` or `x` is null. Check where you are setting their value, or include that part of the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your code: you probably have some sort of declaration similar to: `String line = null;` somewhere before your last piece of code pasted and you get get a `NullPointerException`  at the `list.equals(x.get(i));` line. This is because your `list` object is not initialized. However you don't need to do that. See below.

In order to do what you want you should use the following code:

The class definition for BankAccounts:

```
class BankAccounts {
   public String account; 
   public Double value;

   public BankAccounts(String account, Double value)
   {
      this.account = account;
      this.value = value;
   }
}
```

And rewrite your code like this:

```
List<BankAccounts> x = new ArrayList<BankAccounts>();
try {
    Scanner reader;
    reader = new Scanner( new File("F:\\myCreditUnion.txt") );

    while ( reader.hasNext() )
    {
        String inputLine = reader.nextLine();
        first = inputLine.substring(0, 3);
        second = Double.parseDouble(inputLine.substring(5, inputLine.length()));
        x.add(new BankAccounts(first, second));
    }

    reader.close(); 
}
```

It seems to me that your input files contains line of the form `ABC 10.324`. You are parsing this properly into `BankAccounts` objects (each one containing a `String` representing the account name and a `Double` representing the amount) when you are reading them from file. So there is no need to reparse that again.

The code to iterate and look at the amounts is below;

```
// x is the list    
double howmuch = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
{
    BankAccounts accounts = x.get(i);
    howmuch = accounts.amount; // there is no need to cast since unboxing will occur here.
    // here howmuch will contain the amount for each account
}
```

Comment: Oh, i should clarify i am importing numbers and letters

Comment: Yea.. that much i inferred  :) "line of the form ABC 10.324". But in your second loop you are only trying to reparse what you parsed in when reading from the file.

Comment: O the second loop is a different accessor method

Comment: @joe :) doesn't matter .. you have the proper data already parsed inside the x List objects.